# Is being Noetherian a flat local property of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \longrightarrow Y$ is a flat morphism of schemes and let $Y$ be Noetherian (or locally Noetherian), then will this imply $X$ is also Noetherian (or locally Noetherian)? If not, can someone give me an explicit example?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: As pointed out by Takumi Murayama, this is true in case the condition 'flat' is replced by 'fppf'. Now, is it still true if $Y$ is a Noetherian algebraic stack and $X$ is a scheme and the morphism $X \longrightarrow Y$ is fppf ? I am using here the definition of Noetherian stack as in Stacks Project which states that $Y$ is a Noetherian algebraic stack if for any affine scheme $U$ and any smooth morphism $U \xrightarrow{smooth} Y$, $U$ is Noetherian.

Comment: $\operatorname{Spec}A \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is always flat if $k$ is a field.

Comment: On the other hand, being locally noetherian is fppf-local \[Stacks, [Tag 034C](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/034C)\].

Comment: I see...thanks!